# NPM component - Strava

Tags: node.js, npm

i'm currently trying to use **Strava** api through NPM but i'm facing an issue with strava_config file.

Each time i launch my page in browser i get an error in the console *"no 'data/strava_config' file, continuing without..."* but the folder and file exists. So i don't see what i'm missing. I don't think it's related to the path.

My strava_config look like this (i've removed the values of course)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHOo.png)

Comment: Wich npm package are you using?
Does your server serve the file to your browser?

Comment: i'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/strava-v3 and browserify to output the js file.